# SSRS 2016 Branding/Style Sheets

Tags: reporting-services

I am currently researching how the branding feature works for SSRS 2016.  What I am wondering is if there is anyway to dynamically choose a branding/style sheet for a report based on a parameter passed into the report?

IE We have multiple uses for a single report, and would like to be able to visually distinguish them easily.  Can there be a (for example) dropdown that would have the 'types' of report as options, and then that would determine which style sheet would be used when the report is generated?

I don't think we want to proceed with experimenting with these style sheets if this isn't possible for now, and I haven't been able to find much information about how these style/branding sheets are used other than they need to be uploaded to the SSRS server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My current understanding is that when you upload a brand package to a 2016 Report Server it replaces the existing package. There certainly doesn't appear to be any way to select a specific brand package on the Site Settings. Happy to be proven wrong if anyone knows differently.